# Which is smaller? Python string of booleans or booleans encoded onto an string integer

Tags: python

I would like to periodically message to a cloud based amqp service via cellular telemetry. Each batch of data represents 32 discrete values. The more I shave off the data the more I save in data cost.

I have to send the data as a string. Should I send the data as a series of 32 ones and zeros or should I encode the 32 discrete values into an integer?

The language is python.

Comment: If it's sent as a string, then you sent it as a ASCII encoded character. Here each character is encoded as one byte.

Comment: Depends in how you "send" the batches.

Comment: @OptimusCrime "String" does not necessarily prescribe "ASCII". It's in fact extremely vague what the possibilities are here.

Comment: @deceze Yeah, I guess. It just sounded like he was attempting to send a string ones and zeroes.

Comment: I believe the AMQP standard is UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer is pretty obvious. A 32-char long string is 32 bytes data to transmit. A 32-bit integer is 4 bytes long to send.

I guess here is your answer

Comment: You could also send a bytestring, each byte containing 8 values of the batch. That's also 4 bytes.